# twilio and rails 5.1 compatibility

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio, ruby-on-rails-5, twilio-api

I created a brand new rails 5 app with nothing but the skeleton. When I created a simple welcome controller/home page the server ran fine.

But when I added `gem 'twilio-ruby'` to my app, everything broke down. I wasn't able to run the server, I wasn't able to generate a controller or scaffolds, etc...

This is the error I am receiving:

> C:/Ruby242-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/libxml-ruby-3.0.0-x64-mingw32/lib/libxml.rb:7:in `require': cannot load such file -- libxml_ruby (LoadError)

And it's always that one file too.

Is there a workaround? Is there a compatibility issue with rails 5.1.4/ ruby 2.4.2 and Twilio's ruby api?

When I looked up tutorials of Twilio and rails 5, the gem seemed to work fine for everyone else...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds like you need to install developer tools for osx.

Comment: OP is definitely on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I was going to say that I think, since you are on Windows, that to fully install libxml-ruby [you also need  to install `libxml-ruby-x64-mingw32`](https://github.com/xml4r/libxml-ruby#installation). Try adding both `libxml-ruby-x64-mingw32` and `libxml-ruby` to your `Gemfile` and installing with `bundle install` again.

But then I saw `libxml-ruby-3.0.0-x64-mingw32` in the path of the error, so that might not be it. I'd still try adding both gems to your `Gemfile` first though.

I'd also try installing `libxml-ruby` globally with `gem install libxml-ruby` to see if that helps too.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'twilio-ruby', '~> 5.6'
```

Then head over to your command line terminal and run:

```
bundle
```

Then, you are going to need to secure your credentials with dotenv by pasting this into your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]
```

Head over to your command line terminal again and run:

```
bundle
```

and

```
touch .env
```

The `.env` file is where your Twilio credentials will go. Then you want to test to make sure your Rails app has successfully stored your Twilio API credentials by going to:

```
rails c
```

In the Rails console type:

```
ENV['TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER']
```

If you do not get the phone number provided to you by Twilio, you may need to exit the `rails console` and type in command line:

```
spring stop
```

Head back to your `rails console` and then run:

```
ENV['TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER']
```

This time you should get your phone number to output.This means your Twilio Ruby gem and API credentials are successfully working.

These are the preliminary steps you need to follow in order to avoid any problems.